# Cross Reference Columns ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble selecting all values from a table.
I need to select all vehicles where their vRentTimes value is the same as the times they appear in the Renting table.
So basically just checking if the recordings of rentings are correct.

This is the description of tables:

---

Vehicle

```sql
Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
VPLATENUMBER NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7)  
VCOLOR       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
VCC          NOT NULL NUMBER       
VHORSEPOWER  NOT NULL NUMBER       
VRENTTIMES            NUMBER       
VEHCATNAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
```

---

Renting

```sql
Name         Null?    Type        
------------ -------- ----------- 
CAFM         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(9) 
VPLATENUMBER NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7) 
OUTDATE      NOT NULL DATE        
INDATE                DATE
```

Comment: Pleas edit your question to show the query you've tried, and include example data to demonstrate cases where it didn't work and what results you actually wanted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The post says, that the result should be all the rows from `Vehicle` where each row's `vRentTimes` is the same as the number of times that row's `vPlateNumber` appears in `Renting`

Answer (score 0):

I see.  `vRentTimes` is supposed to be a count for the second table.  You can use `JOIN` and `aggregation.  To get the rows that do not match:

```
select v.*, r.cnt
from vehicles v left join
     (select VPLATENUMBER, count(*) as cnt
      from renting r
      group by VPLATENUMBER
     ) r
     on r.VPLATENUMBER = v.VPLATENUMBER
where v.VRENTTIMES <> coalesce(cnt, 0);
```

Comment: `vRentTimes` is not correlated to the recordings in the `Renting` table. It was inputted by hand and it's not how many times that record appears in `Renting`.

Comment: @Filip . . . You are not the OP so how would you know this?

Comment: He is my friend, we are working on this together.